# Почему содержание письма пустое на яндексе?

Tags: php

После регистрации отправляется письмо с активацией,в котором содержится ссылка с активацией и приветствие от администрации. На mail.ru приходит все нормально, а вот на яндекс пустое сообщение, но тему приписывает правильно, а самого сообщения с активацией нет, пусто.

```
 <?
if ($result2=='TRUE')
   {
      $result3 = mysql_query ("SELECT id FROM users WHERE login='$login'",$db);//извлекаем идентификатор пользователя. Благодаря ему у нас и будет уникальный код активации, ведь двух одинаковых идентификаторов быть не может.
      $myrow3 = mysql_fetch_array($result3);
      $activation = md5($myrow3['id']).md5($login);//код активации аккаунта. Зашифруем через функцию md5 идентификатор и логин. Такое сочетание пользователь вряд ли сможет подобрать вручную через адресную строку.

        $subject = "Подтверждение регистрации";//тема сообщения
        $message = "Здравствуйте! Спасибо за регистрацию на v-sporte.net\nВаш логин: ".$login."\n
 Перейдите по ссылке, чтобы активировать ваш аккаунт:\nhttp://v-sporte.net/activation.php?login=".$login."&code=".$activation."\nС уважением,\n
 Администрация v-sporte.net";//содержание сообщение
 mail($email, $subject, $message, "Content-type:text/plane; Charset=utf-8\r\n");//отправляем сообщение

echo "Вам на E-mail выслано письмо с cсылкой, для подтверждения регистрации. Внимание! Ссылка действительна 1 час. <a href='index.php'>Главная страница</a>"; //говорим о отправленном письме пользователю
```

}

```
else {
  exit ("Ошибка! Вы не зарегистрированы."); //останавливаем выполнение сценариев

 }
?>
```

Comment: `text/plane` -> `text/plain`, для начала

Comment: Все, нормально, спасибо!